# After devtool build image, files can be found in rootfs, but not found when I run on QEMU

Tags: yocto, openbmc

I used `devtool build-image` to include recipe in workspace.

I found corresponding files in rootfs, but couldn't find files when I use QEMU to mount image.

Here's what I done.

1. clone openBMC
2. build image for meta-evb-ast2500

   ```
   export TEMPLATECONF=meta-evb/meta-evb-aspeed/meta-evb-ast2500/conf
   . openbmc-env
   ```
3. `bitbake obmc-phosphor-image`
4. successful
5. `devtool add bbexample https://github.com/whbruce/bbexample.git`
6. `devtool build-image obmc-phosphor-image`
7. files could be found in fs

   ```
   $ find tmp/work/evb_ast2500-openbmc-linux-gnueabi/obmc-phosphor-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/ -name '*bbexample*'
   tmp/work/evb_ast2500-openbmc-linux-gnueabi/obmc-phosphor-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/bin/bbexample
   tmp/work/evb_ast2500-openbmc-linux-gnueabi/obmc-phosphor-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/lib/libbbexample.so.1
   tmp/work/evb_ast2500-openbmc-linux-gnueabi/obmc-phosphor-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/lib/libbbexample.so.1.0.0
   ```
8. start QEMU

   ```
   qemu-system-arm -m 256 -M ast2500-evb -nographic \
   -drive file=$(ls tmp/deploy/images/evb-ast2500/obmc-phosphor-image-evb-ast2500-*.static.mtd),format=raw,if=mtd \
   -net nic \
   -net user,hostfwd=:127.0.0.1:2222-:22,hostfwd=:127.0.0.1:2443-:443,hostname=qemu
   ```
9. These files were not found

These files should have been included in image, right?

Something wrong?

Comment: do you include `bbexample` in `obmc-phosphor-image` with [IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " bbexample"](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage-localconf) in `local.conf` file?

Comment: You're right. After add it into IMAGE_INSTALL, it works. Thanks a lot